# How can I trace an image (footage), from frame to frame, on a separate layer?

Tags: drawing, adobe-after-effects

I want to trace over each frame in some footage, that is not drawing on the original layer of the footage. How can I achieve this in Adobe AE?

I am sure I can do this in Photoshop, but is there a way to do it in AE and if so, would the quality be much better – or will Photoshop be the best tool for it?

Answer (score 2):

What you're searching for is called [Rotoscoping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotoscoping).

You can use After Effects to achieve what you ask for, similar to [this clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8ZS_EiTQro).

You can then use the Paint tool to do your drawing in a new layer. There are plenty of options for the brushes, as you can see in the [Adobe Help Center](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/paint-tools-brush-clone-stamp.html).